# Rails session losing one key:value pair between actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a before_filter that ensures `session[:event_id]` exists and redirects to `select_event` if it doesn't.  `select_event` sends an ajax call to `choose_event_by_keycode`.  `choose_event_by_keycode` then sets `session[:event_id]` and redirects to the index.  The problem is that the `check_event_permissions` filter does not have `session[:event_id]` when it is called.  What is happening?

```
before_filter :check_event_permission, :except => [:select_event, :choose_event_by_keycode]

def check_event_permission
  puts "@!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
  puts session
  puts "@!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
  redirect_to :action =>'select_event' if !session[:event_id]
end     

def choose_event_by_keycode
  @event = Event.find_by_keyCode(params[:keyCode])
  if @event
    current_user.add_to_event_as_patron(@event.id)
    session[:event_id] = @event.id
    puts "!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
    puts session
    puts "!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
    redirect_to mobile_path
  else
    render 'select_event', :notice => "No event found with that key.", :layout => false
  end
end
```

Server Logs (whitespace modified for clarity, and moved puts output so they show in order of ops):

```
Started GET "/mobile/choose_event_by_keycode?keyCode=12345" for 192.168.5.101 at 2012-05-01 12:29:53 -0400
Processing by MobileController#choose_event_by_keycode as */*
  Parameters: {"keyCode"=>"12345"}
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`keyCode` = '12345' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  EventPatron Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `event_patrons`.* FROM `event_patrons` WHERE     `event_patrons`.`user_id` = 1 AND `event_patrons`.`event_id` = 1
!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
{"session_id"=>"ea0a0930f7723719d5c29c722ab3d1ed", "_csrf_token"=>"jzhMJcs2lcsGc9LFZi5PhJbGRG1mTrznFeawWHdUOHk=", "user_id"=>1, "user_type"=>"super", "event_id"=>1}
!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Redirected to http://192.168.5.205:3000/mobile
Completed 302 Found in 259ms (ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)


Started GET "/mobile" for 192.168.5.101 at 2012-05-01 12:29:54 -0400
Processing by MobileController#index as */*
@!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
{"session_id"=>"ea0a0930f7723719d5c29c722ab3d1ed", "_csrf_token"=>"jzhMJcs2lcsGc9LFZi5PhJbGRG1mTrznFeawWHdUOHk=", "user_id"=>1, "user_type"=>"super"}
@!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Redirected to http://192.168.5.205:3000/mobile/select_event
Filter chain halted as :check_event_permission rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

From the logs you can see that `session[:event_id]` is successfully being set in `choose_event_by_keycode`, but then disappears in `check_event_permission`

**UPDATE**

I found the problem.  Turns out this was only occurring if you log out and back in.  In my logout function I had:

```
reset_session
session[:user] = nil
```

Don't ask me why `session[:user] = nil` was even there.  BUT, I removed that and everything worked fine.  SOOOO, the question now becomes `Why did having session[:user] = nil cause the observed behavior?`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you changed your routes so that `choose_event_by_keycode` is actually `GET "/mobile/choose_event?keyCode=12345"`because you aren't showing us choose_event if you aren't.

Also, is your @event there too?  if it's blank or something.... it'd munge that up as  you set it.  maybe add `puts @event.id` to your `puts` statement somewhere... just to verify.

What does the `/mobile` look like?  Something isn't adding up, for sure.

and is this  your real db column name? `keyCode` #curious.

Comment: I have checked that, it is there.  Additionally, you can see that `:event_id => 1`. If `@event` didn't exist, that `puts` would never execute, and if `@event.id` were nil then we'd see `:event_id => nil` in the first `puts`, right?.

Comment: in the sport of debugging it's never as clear cut as that. You could have not sacrificed the right goat, who knows. When stuff don't work, it sucks, that's all i know.

Comment: `match "/mobile" => "mobile#index" ,:as => "mobile"`

Comment: `  def index
    render :partial => "index"
  end 
`

Comment: that is the real db column name, maybe that makes me an idiot?  I certainly hope so.

Comment: The index partial has nothing exciting in, just flat html at the moment.  mobile controller is `layout false`